# How to export multiple classes with a C++/CLI wrapper library for a native C++ library

Tags: c++, export, wrapper, command-line-interface

I have a native C++ library (let's call it CoreLib.dll) and it exposes two classes:

- Core.h
- Atom.h

I have a CLI/C++ wrapper (let's call it CoreWrapper.dll) that allows .NET projects to instantiate `Core` and `Atom` objects:

- CoreDotNet.h
- AtomDotNet.h (includes Atom.h and CoreDotNet.h)

When I compile the CoreWrapper, only `CoreDotNet.h` gets compiled and `AtomDotNet.h` gets ignored. If I want to compile `AtomDotNet.h`, then I must include it in `CoreDotNet.h`, but that causes a compiler error in `CoreDotNet.h`:

```
error C2011: 'CoreWrapperNS::CoreDotNet' : 'class' type redefinition
```

Here is some basic code that represents what I'm doing:

```
#pragma once // <-- should protect from class type redefinition
#include "Core.h"
//#include "AtomDotNet.h" // uncommenting causes compiler error C2011

using namespace CoreNS;

namespace CoreWrapperNS
{
    public ref class CoreDotNet
    {
    public:
        // Allows users to instantiate a core object
        CoreDotNet();
        CoreDotnet(Core* core);
        //... destructor follows
    };
}
```

Here is the AtomDotNet.h file:

```
#pragma once // <-- should protect from class type redefinition
#include "Atom.h"
#include "CoreDotNet.h"

namespace CoreWrapperNS
{
    public ref class AtomDotNet
    {
    private:
        Atom*       _atom;
        CoreDotNet^ _core;
    public:
        AtomDotNet()
        {
            // The atom allows users to instantiate an atom with a core
            // and to get a reference to the core of the given atom.
            Core* core = new Core();
            _atom = new Atom(core);
            _core = gcnew CoreDotNet(core);
        }

        inline CoreDotNet^ GetCore(){return _core;}
        //... destructor follows
    };
}
```

The CoreWrapper project has a reference to the CoreLib project. I've seen some posts around the "Internets" about CLI/C++ wrappers getting the above mentioned compiler error because they reference the C++ project AND they include the header file, but I didn't have that problem until I added a second class (i.e. the `AtomDotNet` class) to the wrapper library and I tried to compile it. Any ideas on what might be happening here?

Comment: Nevermind.  I see the #pragma once.

Comment: @Ben Voigt at this time I don't have .cpp files for the DotNet wrapper library... the header files are thin wrappers around the native C++ library so they just have inline functions that call the corresponding functions on the native object instantiated in the constructor.

Comment: @Lirik: The compiler only compiles .cpp files and the headers they include (unless you totally mangled the compiler options).  It sounds like this lack of .cpp files is part of your problem.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, that was the problem... I added the CPP files and everything works good now!

Comment: @Ben Voigt, please post the comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merely writing your code in header files doesn't cause it to be included in the project.

You need to add .cpp files to the project, and `#include` the headers.

Answer (score 1):

C++/CLI does NOT require headers, in fact one of the advantages that C++/CLI proclames is that it does away with the headers and uses reflection to gain the information it needs that would normally be included in a header.  Rename your .h to .cpp and forget about .h except in native code.

To use the managed classes defined in another .CPP file in the same project, use the '#using' (similar to #include) for the obj file in CoreDotNet.cpp as follows:

```
#using "AtomDotNet.obj"
```

Also, in you CoreDotNet.cpp properties page or in your project properties, under C/C++ on the Resolve #using reference add "$(IntDir)" path so it can find the file when compiling.

This is the C++/CLI way, no more DLL hell and no more .h hell!

Answer (score -2):

C++/CLI does not have the concept of header files. The declaration in a header file is its implementation. So including "CoreDotNet.h" in "AtomDotNet.h" is the issue.

If you have CoreDotNet.cpp that just contains:

```
#include "CoreDotNet.h"
```

and a similar pattern for "AtomDotNet.h", then remove the "CoreDotNet.h" include from "AtomDotNet.h" you should be able to compile it.

You need to treat C++/CLI like you would a C# project and related classes/*.cs files.

Comment: How would AtomDotNet know about CoreDotNet; additionally, how would the compiler know to compile AtomDotNet (right now it only compiles CoreDotNet if I don't include "AtomDotNet.h" in the CoreDotNet header).

Comment: Totally wrong.  C++/CLI not only understands header files, it requires them (well, that or putting all your code into one humongous file, which definitely would not be recommended).  C# lets you refer to a type defined in another file of the same project.  With C++/CLI, this is not possible, you must `#include` the declaration into the current compilation unit.